# Connecting Google Adwords with QlikView 11 without using the QVSource Connector

Tags: sql, google-ads-api, qlikview

I'm working on a project to connect Google Adwords with QlikView 11, i want to know if there's another way to do that without using the QVSource Connector which is not free.

I did some research and i found Adwords API, but i don't know how to use it.
If you have an idea please help me.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You need OAuth2 to authenticate against Adwords. Qlikview support only very simple authentication method (against web sites). Also QV doesn't support data in JSON format.

For this reasons you are unable to connect to Adwords directly from QV. You will need some tool/service that connect and extract the data in format the QV can load.

QVSource is working on this principle. Taking the authentication, extraction and transformation (if needed) of the data to csv format.

So you need to go with QVSource or write an app that will "link" QV with Adwords.

Stefan

Comment: thank you so much Stefan for your answer, i did connect QlikView with Adwords using the QVSource connector and its working very well, unfortunately there isn't another way to do it, because this connector is not free.
your answer helped me to stop searching for another way, and wasting time.